# Transparency on background influence the text

Tags: css, transparency

On my website, I have a slider with some text placed upon it. I've given the text a black, transparant background, so it would be a bit more readable.

[image]

As you can see, it's exactly the effect I'm trying to achieve. But for some reason, my CSS does influence the text too with it's opacity filter...
The text isn't 100% white anymore. Is there a way to overrule this kind of CSS behavior?

**EDIT**: IE8 should be supported...

This is my CSS:

```
.front-slider-body {
  background-color: #000;
  zoom: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: please add the markup as well, it can be quite helpful to know the DOM structure dealt.

Answer (score 3):

Thats because the whole elements `opacity` has been changed, not just the background.

If you want just the `background-color` to be opaque then change the opacity of that property by using `rgba` instead of a hex code:

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
```

---

Full class:

```
.front-slider-body {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
  zoom: 1;
}
```

---

The following shows a list of browsers which this is supported in:

http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba

If you need to support older browsers, then I would recommend creating a 1px*1px semi-transparent image and use that as a `background-image`. It's not tidy, but its a solution for old browsers.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
background-color: #000;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
opacity: 0.5;
```

use

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
```

`rgba()` is available on `IE>8` and will affect the background only, leaving text and nested elements with full opacity

Comment: Meaning IE8 will be supported as well? Or only IE8 is supported?

Comment: `IE>8` means IE9 and IE10. On IE8 and older you still need to use a filter as fallback or a transparent png as background

Answer (score 0):

### Modern browsers (IE9+, FF, Chrome)

Provide transparency just for your background and not the whole element (as others have pointed out) by using

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
```

### Older browsers (including IE7+)

Older browsers<sup>*(of the Microsoft kind)*</sup> don't support `rgba` so in this case you can use PNG with alpha channel to achieve the same result (and would also work in modern browsers):

```
background-image: url(transBack.png);
```

Your PNG should be coloured black with 50% transparency.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try separating the background from the text. The text inherits the opacity of it's parent, which is the problem you're facing. To fix this, set the background as a sibling of the text. So, instead of:

```
// Just example layout
<div id="container" style="background: #000; opacity: 0.5;">
    Your Text
</div>
```

You might try:

```
<div id="container" style="position: relative;">
    <div id="background" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; opacity: 0.5;" ></div>
    <div id="text">Your Text</div>
</div>
```

(obviously, you'd use classes and more cross-browser compliant CSS - this is just to demonstrate the concept)